# Redirect a dynamic URL with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, url

I need to make a Apache rule to redirect an specific URL

http://www.domain.cl/section.do?one.second=8  --> http://www.newdomain.cl/

I was reading about using mod rewrite but all the examples i found use regular expressions and i don't want to other URL (like www.domain.cl/section.do?one.second=9) was affected for the rule that i want to create.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The query string isn't part of the URI as far as mod_rewrite is concerned, so you need to specifically check its contents.  If you want to redirect for just that one specific URI and one specific exact query string, then you'll want..

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^one\.second=8$
RewriteRule ^/section\.do$ http://www.newdomain.cl/ [R=301,L]
```